Как убрать "приветствие" от microsoft в ConEmu?
Установлен clink внутри ConEmu, приветствие от данного дополнения убрал, а то, что на картинке я так понимаю уже от ConEmu, как его убрать?


Вообще-то это от самой cmd.
Ну запускай как cmd /k cls - тогда будет только пустая строка.
Впрочем, я не помню, умеет ли ConEmu чиститься...
